How to center the whole block of a flexbox?
I have multiple DIVs (the DIVs can be generated from an array, so I don't know the number of DIVs beforehand) of different widths. I'm using flexbox with flex-wrap to order them like so:

.outercontainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 400px;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 5px;
}
.wide {
  width: 200px;
}
.normal {
  width: 100px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
}

https://codepen.io/pandaquests/pen/RNbGNLd
This all looks good except there is a space on the right hand side:

Ideally it should look like this (space on the left and right of the whole block is equal):

Is there a way to center the whole block? I tried justify-content:center, but this would center the last two elements as well. I tried grid with grid-auto-flow: row dense; but that would make the items overlap:

.outercontainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 400px;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
.wide {
  width: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
.normal {
  width: 100px;
}
.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
}

https://codepen.io/pandaquests/pen/pvzEvPE
I tried to prevent this using grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr)); and auto-fit (instead of auto-fill), and grid-column:span 2  it still doesn't work.

No, this is not possible with flexbox or CSS-Grid.

Even if you add another internal wrapper there is no way to "collapse" it to just the width of the elements within it.

I think you should try 'justify-content: space-between;' in .container.

Paulie_D is correct, the wrapping child is the issue, in order to 'wrap' it would first needs to take all available width. Once the width is gobbled up by the inner wrapper, there's nothing left to center by the outer container. Practically though, you might get way by faking it a bit, IE: adding padding on the outer container, setting a max-width on the inner container, treating the last element differently by wrapping them specifically, or justjustify-content:center to have it 'close enough'.

You have to think otherwise and get the elements fill the entire width of their cell area instead shrinking the whole grid to what is inside the cells. columns are here set to minmax(100px, 1fr) it won't be different.
To keep only a 400px width at the most , you may try to update padding values according to the view port (or the parent container)
examples & codepen to play with :

grid : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KwPgdbP



.outercontainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0 calc(50cqw - 200px);
  margin:1em
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: .5em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.wide {
  min-width: 200px;
  background: pink;
  grid-column: span 2
}

.normal {
  min-width: 100px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
}

section {
  container-type: inline-size;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wide item">item1</div>
    <div class="normal item">item2</div>
    <div class="normal item">item3</div>
    <div class="normal item">item4</div>
    <div class="normal item">item5</div>
    <div class="normal item">item6</div>
    <div class="normal item">item7</div>
    <div class="normal item">item8</div>
    <div class="normal item">item9</div>
    <div class="normal item">item10</div>
  </div>
</div>
<section>
  <div class="outercontainer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="wide item">item1</div>
      <div class="normal item">item2</div>
      <div class="normal item">item3</div>
      <div class="normal item">item4</div>
      <div class="normal item">item5</div>
      <div class="normal item">item6</div>
      <div class="normal item">item7</div>
      <div class="normal item">item8</div>
      <div class="normal item">item9</div>
      <div class="normal item">item10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section>




flex https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qEWabEp



body {
  margin: 0;
}

.outercontainer {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0 calc(50cqw - 200px);
  margin: 1em
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: .5em;
}

.item.wide {
  min-width: 200px;
  flex: 2;
  background: pink;
}

.normal {
  min-width: 100px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 30px;
  flex: 1;
}

section {
  container-type: inline-size;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
<div class="outercontainer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wide item">item1</div>
    <div class="normal item">item2</div>
    <div class="normal item">item3</div>
    <div class="normal item">item4</div>
    <div class="normal item">item5</div>
    <div class="normal item">item6</div>
    <div class="normal item">item7</div>
    <div class="normal item">item8</div>
    <div class="normal item">item9</div>
    <div class="normal item">item10</div>
  </div>
</div>
<section>
  <div class="outercontainer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="wide item">item1</div>
      <div class="normal item">item2</div>
      <div class="normal item">item3</div>
      <div class="normal item">item4</div>
      <div class="normal item">item5</div>
      <div class="normal item">item6</div>
      <div class="normal item">item7</div>
      <div class="normal item">item8</div>
      <div class="normal item">item9</div>
      <div class="normal item">item10</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section>



This seems quiet close to your needs.
